# I am getting error when apex method is called from lightning controller to insert a record in Expense Object

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, sfsolute__Expense__c: bad field names on insert/update call: Amount__c, Client__c: [Amount__c, Client__c]

when I tried to debug Expense__c passed I got debugs as attached screenshot[image]

My Component is as below

```
<aura:component controller="insertExpense">
        <aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="Expense__c"
     default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Expense__c',
                    'Amount__c': 0,
                    'Client__c': '',
                    }"/>
    <form >
     <div >
              <ui:inputNumber label="Amount"
                  value="{!v.newExpense.Amount__c}"
                  required="true"/>
  </div>

      <div >
              <ui:inputText label="Client"
                  value="{!v.newExpense.Client__c}"
                  placeholder="ABC Co."/>
      </div>

      <div >
          <ui:button label="Create Expense"
              press="{!c.clickCreateExpense}"/>
      </div>     
    </form>  
</aura:component>



My Component Controller 


({
    clickCreateExpense : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.insertExpenseMethod");
        var expense = component.get("v.newExpense");
        action.setParams({"exp": expense});
        action.setCallback(this, function() {
        console.log('SAVED.'); 
    });

         $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class insertExpense {
    @AuraEnabled public static void insertExpenseMethod(Expense__c exp){
        System.debug(exp);
        System.debug('exp.Amount__c'+exp.Amount__c);
        System.debug('exp.Client__c'+exp.Client__c);
        //Expense__c expObj = new Expense__c(amount__c = exp.Amount__c ,client__c= exp.Client__c);
        upsert exp;

    }
}
```

Comment: have tried adding namespace to the aura:attribute? for:example:
`<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="sfsolute__Expense__c"
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'sfsolute__Expense__c',
'Name': '',
'sfsolute__Amount__c': 0,
'sfsolute__Client__c': ''}  />`

Comment: Yes I tried . then I thought it might be happenig because of date so I have removed date and isreimbursed fields

Comment: Are you able to perform an upsert in developer console using only these two fields without lightning component? Frequently, an upsert requires an `external Id field`. In your case, I wouldn't expect that, just a unique `Amount__c` for a `Client__c` on a particular `Date`. Perhaps the date is what you're missing?

Comment: I did in anonymous window its working fine. and before upsert I tried insert it was giving same error

Comment: Please try to set only the aura:attribute type with the namespace: `<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="sfsolute__Expense__c" ...` and all other without the namespace. If that does not work - try setting only the sobjectType within the json to be with the namespace: `default="{ 'sobjectType': 'sfsolute__Expense__c'` and all others without the namespace